# Not able to add my own css to magento2

Tags: magento-2.1, css

I created a **default.xml** file at **\app\design\frontend\nitish\Lucowatch\Magento_theme\layout** and add the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="css/styles-m.css" />
    <css src="css/styles-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>
    <css src="css/print.css" media="print" />
    <css src="css/bootstrap.min.css" media="print" />
    <css src="css/font_family.css" media="print" />
    <css src="css/mystyle.css" media="print" />
    <css src="css/theme.css" media="print" />
</head>
```

but I did not find css when I go on home page

Comment: Have you tried clearing caches and deleting `var/view_preprocessed` and `pub/static/frontend`?

Comment: media="print" means this stylesheet is only available when printing, remove that and refresh the cache.

Comment: Yes I did clearing caches many times..but not working after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give this a try:
you can find **default_head_blocks.xml** in your theme at **vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\layout**
just put inside head tag

```
<head>
 <css src="css/customcss.css" />
</head>
```

after that copy default_head_blocks.xml to your theme.

Comment: welcome Nitish Kumar...

Comment: If you don't mind can I ask you something again?
I did that again. Actually I had to add some more files so after that I did the same process and after that I deploy my content and now my old static css have also gone. I don't know what this happen. and now I'm repeating the same process but after that my static css are not including. Could you help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After adding the css file in head block you have to deploy static content and flush the cache like :

```
cd /var/www/html/project root directory
sudo bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
sudo bin/magento cache:flush
```